# What's the main menu background screen in Minecraft 1.8 based off?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm referring to the blurry scenery in the background.

Is it just randomly generated? Is it sometimes based off worlds you've made? Or is it neither?

[image: Background Screen]

Comment: @Gnome apparently at least 7 people.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is a mesh of 6 PNG files displayed sequentially (and with a *wonderful* transition!).  These files are located inside your `minecraft.jar` inside `title/bg` (So yes, you can change them).

Source: I found them while browsing the jar, then stared at the background to confirm that they matched.

Also, the 2 computers I tested had the same files, so it stands to reason that `minecraft.jar` does *not* dynamically generate them.

Comment: For purposes of trying to improve this and future answers, why the downvote?

Comment: Not sure. Loved your answer though. Clear and to the point.

Answer (score 5):

As john said it's located in the minecraft.jar file inside title/bg. Here's a little video on how to change it :D

Comment: The video is private, please link a different one to make your answer complete :)